# phusion passenger on apache : Could not spawn process for group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I want to install gitlabhq on Debian linux

I installed gitlabhq [ that it is a rails application ]
i installed phusio passenger on apache for serving application.
but gitlabhq doesn`t start

i have this error message in /var/log/apache2/error

```
    [Mon Nov 04 07:11:24 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[ 2013-11-04 07:11:25.8690 8321/b6f52000 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:574 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_instances_per_app' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.23', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_pid' => '8320', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-11-04 07:11:25.9032 8324/b6f35000 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:619 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.8320/generation-0/request
[ 2013-11-04 07:11:25.9528 8330/b6886220 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.8320/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-11-04 07:11:25.9545 8321/b6f52000 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:761 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2013-11-04 07:11:31.3236 8377/b6ff0000 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:574 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_instances_per_app' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.23', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_pid' => '8341', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-11-04 07:11:31.3589 8380/b6f1d000 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:619 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.8341/generation-0/request
[ 2013-11-04 07:11:31.4075 8386/b67e0220 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.8341/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-11-04 07:11:31.4092 8377/b6ff0000 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:761 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[Mon Nov 04 07:11:31 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Phusion_Passenger/4.0.23 configured -- resuming normal operations
[ 2013-11-04 07:11:31.4780 8380/b52bf450 Pool2/Spawner.h:796 ]: [App 8453 stdout] 
[ 2013-11-04 07:13:01.6074 8380/b52bf450 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:849 ]: Could not spawn process for group /home/git/gitlabhq#default: An error occurred while starting the web application: it did not write a startup response in time.
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::throwAppSpawnException(const string&, Passenger::SpawnException::ErrorKind, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::NegotiationDetails&)' (Spawner.h:689)
     in 'Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::negotiateSpawn(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::NegotiationDetails&)' (Spawner.h:1194)
     in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::DirectSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (DirectSpawner.h:213)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:782)

[ 2013-11-04 07:13:01.6092 8380/b5aff450 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1995 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session.
Error page:
An error occurred while starting the web application: it did not write a startup response in time. Please read <a href="https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems">this article</a> for more information about this problem.<br>
<h2>Raw process output:</h2>
(empty)
[Mon Nov 04 07:42:46 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[ 2013-11-04 07:42:47.8189 8665/b6f64000 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:574 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_instances_per_app' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.23', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_pid' => '8664', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-11-04 07:42:47.8683 8668/b6faa000 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:619 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.8664/generation-0/request
[ 2013-11-04 07:42:47.9175 8673/b6832220 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.8664/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-11-04 07:42:47.9191 8665/b6f64000 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:761 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2013-11-04 07:42:48.3361 8705/b6f0b000 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:574 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_instances_per_app' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.23', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_pid' => '8685', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-11-04 07:42:48.3722 8708/b6efa000 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:619 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.8685/generation-0/request
[ 2013-11-04 07:42:48.4219 8713/b6810220 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.8685/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-11-04 07:42:48.4235 8705/b6f0b000 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:761 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[Mon Nov 04 07:42:48 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Phusion_Passenger/4.0.23 configured -- resuming normal operations
[ 2013-11-04 07:42:53.8737 8708/b529f450 Pool2/Spawner.h:796 ]: [App 8797 stdout] 
[ 2013-11-04 07:44:24.0079 8708/b529f450 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:849 ]: Could not spawn process for group /home/git/gitlabhq#default: An error occurred while starting the web application: it did not write a startup response in time.
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::throwAppSpawnException(const string&, Passenger::SpawnException::ErrorKind, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::NegotiationDetails&)' (Spawner.h:689)
     in 'Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::negotiateSpawn(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::NegotiationDetails&)' (Spawner.h:1194)
     in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::DirectSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (DirectSpawner.h:213)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:782)

[ 2013-11-04 07:44:24.0090 8708/b5adf450 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:1995 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session.
Error page:
An error occurred while starting the web application: it did not write a startup response in time. Please read <a href="https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems">this article</a> for more information about this problem.<br>
<h2>Raw process output:</h2>
(empty)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install GitLab very fast via Bitnami : http://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab

Answer (score 1):

Follow instructions provided [In this blog by folks at Phusion](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/04/21/tutorial-setting-up-gitlab-on-debian-6/) to run Gitlab on Phusion Passenger

Comment: this url use nginx but i`m using apache web server

Comment: you just have to alter Step 7, to use apache instead on nginx. Run this `sudo passenger-install-apache2-module` instead of `sudo passenger-install-nginx-module`. Follow instructions on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you to read https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems for more information about the problem. That page lists a number of possibilities why you get that error. Have you already gone through them?

The most likely cause for your problem is the last item on that page, "Server too busy". You should follow the instructions there.